# Compare values of pairs of columns w similar name

Tags: r, function

Like most of my questions - this one must have a simple answer. I have looked around here and elsewhere online, and have not found a succinct solution. Y'all know everything, any help is appreciated.

Situation - I have two sets of data both from my org's primary database. Methods to get and aggregate the data differ slightly and I do not have access to both queries to see exactly how they differ. I need to compare counts between them both for each column x row. I can obviously do this longhand (EG w mutate is below for a couple of them) but I have many columns in each and that would take a long time, and be many lines of code. This is not ideal, although I write the scripts, others use them, who have less scripting skill, IE if a person has to make many small edits to many lines of code, they're probably going to make a mistake.

An ideal solution is a basic function that works on field names regardless of their position in the joined dataset. I'm not big into writing complex functions, which is probably a big shortcoming of mine. I am who I am.

EG of data are below, any help is appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)

eg_data1 <- data.frame(
  Group = c('RubberChickens', 'WhoopieCushions', 'FartSpray', 'Tupperware', 'Coffee', 'Bags', 'Scissors', 'Goodfellas'),
  Fall21 = c(1, 18, 38, 28, 34, 92, 34, 16) , 
  Spring22 = c(29, 45, 23, 94, 23, 19, 20, 83) , 
  Fall22 = c(26, 18, 87, 54, 96, 21, 57, 51) ,
  Spring23 = c(58, 41, 54, 92, 71, 15, 51, 84) ,
  Fall23 = c(12, 51, 49, 25, 63, 17, 80, 74))

eg_data2 <- data.frame(
  Group = c('RubberChickens', 'WhoopieCushions', 'FartSpray', 'Tupperware', 'Coffee', 'Bags', 'Scissors', 'Goodfellas'),
  Fall21 = c(1, 19, 34, 28, 33, 92, 34, 17) , 
  Spring22 = c(29, 47, 23, 96, 21, 19, 20, 82) , 
  Fall22 = c(24, 18, 86, 54, 99, 21, 53, 51) ,
  Spring23 = c(58, 43, 54, 92, 79, 15, 53, 84) ,
  Fall23 = c(13, 51, 45, 25, 66, 18, 81, 74))

# The mutate solution below will work, but the real dataset would require this done dozens of times

eg_data1 %>%
  left_join(eg_data2, by = c('Group')) %>%
  mutate(
    CompFall21 = abs(Fall21.x - Fall21.y),
    CompSpring22 = abs(Spring22.x - Spring22.y)) -> eg_data3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a combination of `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()`.

```r
eg_data1 %>% 
  bind_rows(eg_data2, .id = 'source') %>% 
  pivot_longer(Fall21:Fall23) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = c(source),
    values_from = value
  ) %>% 
  rename(
    'eg_data1' = `1`,
    'eg_data2' = `2`
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    diff = abs(eg_data1 - eg_data2)
  )
#> # A tibble: 40 x 5
#>    Group           name     eg_data1 eg_data2  diff
#>    <chr>           <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 RubberChickens  Fall21          1        1     0
#>  2 RubberChickens  Spring22       29       29     0
#>  3 RubberChickens  Fall22         26       24     2
#>  4 RubberChickens  Spring23       58       58     0
#>  5 RubberChickens  Fall23         12       13     1
#>  6 WhoopieCushions Fall21         18       19     1
#>  7 WhoopieCushions Spring22       45       47     2
#>  8 WhoopieCushions Fall22         18       18     0
#>  9 WhoopieCushions Spring23       41       43     2
#> 10 WhoopieCushions Fall23         51       51     0
#> # i 30 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is great and very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

{powerjoin} might help :

```
powerjoin::power_left_join(
  eg_data1,
  eg_data2, 
  by = "Group",
  conflict = ~ abs(.x - .y) # or just conflict = `-` to keep the sign
)
#>             Group Fall21 Spring22 Fall22 Spring23 Fall23
#> 1  RubberChickens      0        0      2        0      1
#> 2 WhoopieCushions      1        2      0        2      0
#> 3       FartSpray      4        0      1        0      4
#> 4      Tupperware      0        2      0        0      0
#> 5          Coffee      1        2      3        8      3
#> 6            Bags      0        0      0        0      1
#> 7        Scissors      0        0      4        2      1
#> 8      Goodfellas      1        1      0        0      0
```

Comment: This is actually both what I had originally asked, and the next thing I needed to do. All in one neat package. Thank you sir! Ren&Stimpy4Lyfe